# "if I told you" or "if I had told you"?

Tags: conditionals

Which of these two sentences is correct:

1) You wouldn't have believed me if I told you last year.

2) You wouldn't have believed me if I had told you last year.

Answer (score 1):

The second is correct without the comma (British "half stop"). In the first, "if I told you last year" indicates it is unknown if this was told.

Comment: removed commas.

Answer (score 0):

Both make sense and should be fine either way you go.

They emphasize different ways to speak. I suggest reading [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56498/as-i-told-you-vs-as-i-have-told-you?newreg=b3402cecb6634207acc4988e0ab84b9b) to somewhat get a better understanding of the uses. It's not the same phrasing but the point should still get across.